# Need help parsing JSON with PHP to build an URL

Tags: php, json, url

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{
"name": "Star_Wars",
"Level": true,
"condition": "HOT",
"actions": [
    {
        "index": 0,
        "name": "Sword_hit",
        "expectedModelName": "SwordModel",
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "LANGUAGE",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "GB"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "PLANET_VERSION",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "HUTTA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "newParameters": [],
        "checks": []
    },
    {
        "index": 1,
        "name": "Sword_bash",
        "expectedModelName": "SwordModel2",
        "params": [
            {
                "name": "LANGUAGE",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "IT"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "PLANET_VERSION",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "value": "SCHNUTTA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "newParameters": [],
        "checks": []
    }
]
```

I am trying to parse it with PHP and build URLs out of it. Each "action" is a URL and the parameters are within the "params" section. So the two URLs should be:

> index0: LANGUAGE=GB&PLANET_VERSION=HUTTA
>
> index1: LANGUAGE=IT&PLANET_VERSION=SCHNUTTA

My code looks like this so far:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("data.json");
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

echo"http://www.myurl.de/test.php?";
foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key=$val&";
    }
}
?>
```

It works as designed but not as desired ;-) I only need the "params" to build the url. But how can I implement a condition, which only targets the "name" and the "values" from "params" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this simplistic solution:

```
$data = json_decode($json);
$urls = array();
foreach($data->actions as $k1=>$v1) {
    $urls[$k1] = '';
    foreach($v1->params as $k2=>$v2) {
        $urls[$k1].= $v2->name.'='.$v2->values[0]->value.'&';
    }
    $urls[$k1] = rtrim($urls[$k1],'&');
}
print_r($urls);
```

Comment: Thank you for this simple but very efficient answer !